# SQL query to count number of items in secondary table using Nested Set model

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on categories using Nested Set model. My DB design is like this

- Table 1: categories (id, lft, rgt, count1, count2)
- Table 2: Items1 (id, catid, .....) -- catid is id from categories table
- Table 3: Items2 (id, item1_id, ....) -- item1_id is id from Items 1 table

Now Since Items1 has catid column, I can easily calculate the count of items down the tree using nested set model using below SQL:

```
        SELECT 
            parent.id, COUNT(items.id) as item_count
        FROM 
            categories AS node ,
            categories AS parent,
            items1 AS items
        WHERE 
            node.nleft BETWEEN parent.nleft AND parent.nright 
            AND node.id = items.catid
            AND items.published = 1
        GROUP BY 
            parent.id
        ORDER BY 
            node.nleft;
```

and update each category from that SQL.

Now can someone please help me how can I update number of items for each category down the tree from items2 table into count2 column?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would set `count2` to the number of rows in `items2` that reference the category:

```
update 
  categories 
set 
  count2=(
    select count(*) from items2 where items2.item1_id in (
      select id from items1 where items1.catid=categories.id
    )
  )
```

To set `count2` to the number of rows in both `items1` and `items2` that reference the category:

```
update 
  categories 
set 
  count2=(
    select count(*) from items2 where items2.item1_id in (
      select id from items1 where items1.catid=categories.id
    ) + 
    select count(*) from items1 where items1.catid=categories.id
  )
```

Comment: I guess my query was not clear. What I want is sum of all categories down the tree. For example consider the category tree path A->B->C, the count in A should be sum of counts in A+B+C where as count in B should be sum of B+C. Please see the SQL above, how I am doing it for item1 counts. I hope I am clear now.

Comment: I expanded my answer, but I am not actually understanding your data model I guess. What are `nleft` and `nright` for?

Comment: It's to facilitate the nested sets model. Nodes with values between nleft and nright of other nodes are children of those nodes, allowing a tree of self referencing items with high queryability

Comment: Thanks @Charleh - I misunderstood the question

Answer (score 0):

Thanks MiMo for your reply. Finally, I am able to do it myself.

What I did is,

1. Added a new column item22_count in items1 table and updating it whenever a new record is inserted into items2 table.
2. Now I modified first query like this to obtain items2 count.

   ```
   SELECT 
       parent.id, sum(items2_count) as item2_count
   FROM 
       categories AS node ,
       categories AS parent,
       items1 AS items
   WHERE 
       node.nleft BETWEEN parent.nleft AND parent.nright 
       AND node.id = items.catid
       AND items.published = 1
   GROUP BY 
       parent.id
   ORDER BY 
       node.nleft;
   ```

I know this has an added overhead of updating the column but that is for a good reason and I found no other way. Thanks anyway for your answers.